# Rails controller rendering wrong view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a pretty typical blog site with posts, which are organized by date, and informational pages, which are organized arbitrarily by title. The main blog section (`posts#index`) is rendering fine, but `pages#index` seems to be rendering the top-level template instead (same as the `root` route), as if the `match '/info'` rule is not being detected properly.

I understand that they are all using the same layout (`application.html.haml`). However, whereas the `/posts` route is properly displaying the `posts/index.html.haml` template, the `/pages` route seems to be falling back, displaying `application/index.html.haml` when it should display `pages/index.html.haml`.

No controller explicitly defines an `index` action. I'm not sure if that's part of the problem, but why would `posts#index` work fine while `pages#index` does not?

routes.rb:

```
Foo::Application.routes.draw do
    root :to => 'application#index'
    match '/blog' => 'posts#index'
    match '/info' => 'pages#index'
end
```

Controllers:

```
# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def show_tag
    @tag = params[:tag]
  end
end

# posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @date = params[:date] 
    end
end

# pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @title = params[:title]
    end
end
```

...and views:

```
# layouts/index.html.haml
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Foo
    %meta{:charset => "utf-8"}
    %meta{"http-equiv" => "X-UA-Compatible", :content => "IE=edge,chrome=1"}
    %meta{:name => "viewport", :content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"}
    = stylesheet_link_tag :application, :media => "all"
    = javascript_include_tag :application
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    #container.container
      %header
        %h1
          = link_to("Home", root_path)
      #main{:role => "main"}
        = yield
      %footer

# application/index.html.haml
%p
  %a{:href => 'blog'} Blog
%p
  %a{:href => 'info'} Info

# posts/index.html.haml
%p List of blog posts
%ul
    %li
        %a{:href => 'blog/6-1'} June 1st
    %li
        %a{:href => 'blog/6-2'} June 2nd

# pages/index.html.haml
%p Info about stuff
%ul
    %li
        %a{:href => 'info/foo'} Foo
    %li
        %a{:href => 'info/bar'} Bar
```

I'm running Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 1.9.3. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem a bit confused on the concept of the [layout](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html). To put it short, the `application.html.erb` file in `views/layouts/` folder is a layout file that defines how the content of your application will be displayed. And there's no such thing called `application#index`.

Comparing your two applications `posts` and `pages`, they both will have the same layout since both using `application.html.erb` as their layouts but with different content(`posts` will display your posts and `pages` will display pages)

Hope this helps

Comment: Regarding `application#index`, what would be more conventional to put in routes.rb?

In any case, the fact that it's using the same **layout** is not exactly the problem; it's of a finer grain than that. :) I edited the post to (hopefully) clarify.

Comment: @acobster We don't put `application#index` in any places. It's not needed in `routes.rb`. You might want to remove that from the routes file and restart the server to see if it changes anything.

Comment: The extraneous route was obfuscating the real problem, which was that the `views/pages/` directory didn't exist! (I was using a save filter to scp it up to the server and didn't notice this before. I feel silly.)